# MySQL scope of alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.DtaId
        FROM Tappt a
        WHERE g.Id = a.TapptGroupsId
    ) AS t0
) AS Id
FROM Tappt t
LEFT JOIN TapptGroups g ON t.TapptGroupsId = g.Id;
```

In MySQL, it throws the error: `Unknown column 'g.Id' in 'where clause'`

The alternative T-SQL code works fine in MS SQL Server with the same schema.

Can someone explain what is the problem, please?

Comment: Hello, the problem is this : WHERE g.Id = a.TapptGroupsId. You have not defined what g is. In your case Tappt a; a only is defined. Another think I would like to mention is expression are always evaluated from inside out. This is a math principle.

Comment: aliases in MySQL only can go one level up or down.. You have two levels ( two nested selects ).

Comment: Do this and you will see that it has no column Id:  "describe TapptGroups"

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ the table 'TapptGroups' has 'Id' column

Comment: @NesanMano 'g' is defined in the line with 'JOIN'

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it as (one nested level):

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.DtaId)
    FROM Tappt a
    WHERE g.Id = a.TapptGroupsId
) AS Id
FROM Tappt t
LEFT JOIN TapptGroups g ON t.TapptGroupsId = g.Id;
```

Comment: the problem is that the SQL is generated by ORM.

Comment: @VladislavTryhub Named query or you could try to set dialect to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `LEFT JOIN` in the outer query.  Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.DtaId)
        FROM Tappt a
        WHERE g.Id = a.TapptGroupsId
       ) AS id
FROM TapptGroups ;
```

Or:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.dtaID)
FROM Tappt t LEFT JOIN
     TapptGroups g
     ON t.TapptGroupsId = g.Id
GROUP BY g.id;
```

MySQL only recognizes correlation clauses one level deep -- Oracle is another database that has this limitation.  You can also fix this by doing an aggregation in the `FROM` clause.